# return std::unique_ptr containing std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap, unique-ptr

I have a map of maps as follows:

```
std::map<char,std::map<short,char>> my_maps;
```

and I need to return a refrence to one of the maps corresponding to an specified key from a function.
I do not know how I should do this ,here is my code:

```
bool GetMap(char key,std::unique_ptr<std::map<short,char>> my_map){


  auto m=my_maps.find(key);
  if(m!=my_maps.end()){

     my_map=m->second;
     // I have also tried this: my_map=my_maps[_commandcode];

    return(true);
  }
  return (false);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a `unique_ptr` (it doesn't make sense); you should probably be returning an iterator instead.

Comment: how else can I return a pointer to this map?!

Comment: A pointer? Isn't that just `&m->second`? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Maybe if you mention what you're trying to do we might be able to offer better solutions. :)

Comment: Pass the map as a reference? You should do that anyway, as otherwise there will be a log of copying.

Comment: Accepting a `std::unique_ptr` means that the `map` passed by the caller will be taken from the caller's scope, and destroyed when the function returns. "`unique`" means that it's the "owning" pointer and that the `map` object cannot exist without it. That is probably not what you want. Pass a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I will do instead:

```
std::map<short,char>& GetMap(char key, std::map<char,std::map<short,char>> &my_maps)
{
  auto m = my_maps.find(key);
  if (m != my_maps.end())
  {
    return m->second;
  }
  throw std::exception("not found");
}
```

Comment: this works fine ,but I need to return a pointer ,not a copy of the map

Comment: @Shohreh Because.... ? This is returning a *reference*, which means *its* address is *the* address of the specified map. If you need a pointer, take the address on the caller size, but honestly I can't see what you would need it for.

Comment: I shamelessly stole idea from @Mehrdad and added exception